# Unable to extract text between two xml tag

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am trying to extract the text between the **compliance-solution** from my nessus file but I am unable to extract some of the text  as there are multiple line of text

```
Here is a sample of the compliance-solution text:
<cm:compliance-solution>Adjust the number of logs to prevent data loss. The default value of 6 may be insufficient for a production environment.
1. Open SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Open Object Explorer and connect to the target instance.
3. Navigate to the Management tab in Object Explorer and expand. Right click on the SQL Server Logs file and select Configure
4. Check the Limit the number of error log files before they are recycled
5. Set the Maximum number of error log files to greater than or equal to 12</cm:compliance-solution>

#!/usr/bin/python
import re


f = open('C:\\<file_path>\\test_file.nessus', 'r')
xml_content = f.readlines()


for line in xml_content:
    m=re.compile('<cm:compliance-solution>(.*?)</cm:compliance-solution>').search(line)
    w=re.compile('<cm:compliance-check-name>(.*?)</cm:compliance-check-name>').search(line)
    x=re.compile('<cm:compliance-result>(.*?)</cm:compliance-result>').search(line)
    y=re.compile('<cm:compliance-reference>(.*?)</cm:compliance-reference>').search(line)
    q=re.compile('<cm:compliance-info>(.*?)</cm:compliance-info>').search(line)
    if x is not None:
        print(x.group(1).split('&apos;'))
    if m is not None:
        print(m.group(1).split('&apos;'))
    if w is not None:
        print(w.group(1))
    if y is not None:
        print(y.group(1))
    if q:
        print(q.group(1))
f.close()
```

Comment: m=re.compile('<cm:compliance-solution>([\S\s]*?)</cm:compliance-solution>').search(xml_content)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex don't compile because you're iterating over the text line by line and the opening tag `<cm:compliance-solution>` is not in the same line as the closing tag `</cm:compliance-solution>`

One option would be to just read the whole file as one string as in:

```
f = open('C:\\<file_path>\\test_file.nessus', 'r')
xml_content = f.read()


m=re.compile('<cm:compliance-solution>(.*?)</cm:compliance-solution>').search(xml_content)
w=re.compile('<cm:compliance-check-name>(.*?)</cm:compliance-check-name>').search(xml_content)
x=re.compile('<cm:compliance-result>(.*?)</cm:compliance-result>').search(xml_content)
y=re.compile('<cm:compliance-reference>(.*?)</cm:compliance-reference>').search(xml_content)
q=re.compile('<cm:compliance-info>(.*?)</cm:compliance-info>').search(xml_content)
if x is not None:
    print(x.group(1).split('&apos;'))
if m is not None:
    print(m.group(1).split('&apos;'))
if w is not None:
    print(w.group(1))
if y is not None:
    print(y.group(1))
if q:
    print(q.group(1))
f.close()
```

If the XML data is more intricate though, I do suggest looking at the xml parser libraries available in python.

Etree: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Defusedxml: https://pypi.org/project/defusedxml/

Comment: hi fritz thank you for the information, but i manage to extract using a method i found online!

Answer (score 0):

Since nessus files are in xml format, you should use an xml parser to extract the data. So if you are after the text of `<cm:compliance-solution`, try something fairly simple like this:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse(r'C:\\<file_path>\\test_file.nessus')
print(doc.xpath('//*[local-name()="compliance-solution"]/text()')[0])
```

output:

> Adjust the number of logs to prevent data loss. The default value of 6
> may be insufficient for a production environment.
>
> 1. Open SQL Server Management Studio.
> 2. Open Object Explorer and connect to the target instance.
> 3. Navigate to the Management tab in Object Explorer and expand. Right click on the SQL Server Logs file and select Configure
> 4. Check the Limit the number of error log files before they are recycled
> 5. Set the Maximum number of error log files to greater than or equal to 12

Comment: hi jack thank you for the information, but i manage to extract using a method i found online!

Answer (score 0):

. represents a match for any single character except the newline character. You can use [\s\S] to match any character. So you can use the following regex to match the data you want. In addition, as fritz said, you get data by row, not complete data.

```
m=re.compile('<cm:compliance-solution>([\S\s]*?)</cm:compliance-solution>').search(xml_content)
```

However, for parsing XML, I recommend that you use an XML parsing library. Here is a reference for you.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
xml_content = utils.getFileContent('C:\\<file_path>\\test_file.nessus')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml_content)
m = doc.select('cm:compliance-solution>html()')
print (m)
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples

Comment: hi dabingsou thank you for the information, but i manage to extract using a method i found online!

Comment: Congratulations! But we are all online:)